# How to start visual diff of working copy and last commit of a file from command line in mercurial TortoiseHg

Tags: linux, qt, mercurial, tortoisehg, diffmerge

Provided that I already know that a file has been modified in a mercurial repo, 
**Is there any way to start a diff tool in command line to show the visual diff of the file** between working copy and commit.

**Little background:**
I`m trying to add a *External Tool* for QT which will help me see currently open file's working copy changes in a diff tool in click of a button without going and opening the repo in TortoiseHg, waiting for it to load (big repo, lot of time), then right clicking modified file to select *view visual diff*

To those who are NOT familiar with the setup, 
**I have:** full path of the hg repo and modified file,
**I need:**  a linux command to open the diff between *working copy* and *last commit* of the file in a diff tool

My setup:
Linux, QT, TortoiseHg, Sourcegear DiffMerge

Is this possible?

Comment: Reading for @yhw42 practical part http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/adding-functionality-with-extensions.html#sec:hgext:extdiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the ability to edit one of the config files to enable extensions, such as the .hgrc file. If that is true, then [as described here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/DiffMerge) or [here](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__mercurial__linux_mac.html) you can add the following (and ensure the path to diffmerge is correct):

```
[ui]
merge = diffmerge

[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.diffmerge = /usr/bin/diffmerge

[merge-tools]
diffmerge.executable = /usr/bin/diffmerge
diffmerge.args = -merge -result=$output -t1="Local Version" -t2=$output -t3="Other Version" -caption=$output $local $base $other
diffmerge.binary = False
diffmerge.symlinks = False
diffmerge.gui = True
```

Since you only asked to add it to diff between files and not for merging, you may only need the following sections (which excludes the merge functions) :

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.diffmerge = /usr/bin/diffmerge
```

Comment: You forgot to write final result: `hg diffmerge FILENAME` in CLI

Comment: What worked for me: I followed yhw42 's instructions and added everything to my .hgrc file. Then, 

1. To see the working dir diff (all changed files), I used hg diffmerge command. 
2. To see the diff of a single file, I used hg diffmerge <FILENAME> like @lazy Badger suggested.

Comment: @user2608651 - all changed files in working dir will be `hg status` better

Comment: @LazyBadger, `hg status` gives me the name of changed files. I want to see all the changed files in a visual diff tool, open a file to see its changes and modify if necessary. `hg diffmerge` serves the purpose.